# filter products by attribute and hide out of stock items of variable products

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to make a filter by attribute for variable products but the problem is that the filter shows out of stock product, and I have to hide the out of stock products checked, but it didn't solve the issue, thanks in advance

Comment: I have the exact same issue. Please let me know how you found the solution.

Comment: -@Jafer.balti I solved it by adding the extension in Woof plugin (instock extension) and then assigned it to be instock and hided it from the front end by using css that appears to customers , so it shows only the instock

Answer (score 0):

This is standard woocommerce functionality, it shows “out of stock” products on the shop page, in the woocommerce widgets, everywhere.

Only on the product single is “Out of stock” shown instead of an “Add to cart”.

1. Go to `Woocommerce → Settings` and click the Products tab
2. Click the `Inventory link` at the top
3. Check the Out Of Stock Visibility option to hide out of stock items

If above option is already checked. Please try below code in your **functions.php file of current theme**.

```
function check_variation_is_active( $active, $variation ) {
  if( ! $variation->is_in_stock() ) {
     return false;
  }
  return $active;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_variation_is_active','check_variation_is_active', 10, 2 );
```

I hope it will help you.
Thanks

Comment: thanks for your comment, but it is already checked , the out of stock products doesn't show in shop page, but they show when filtering by attribute.

Comment: @bayanelshiwy i have edited my answer please check the second method.

Comment: thanks for your comment, but it didn't work , the problem as i have read is that when filtering by attribute of variable product it searches for the parent product not the variations (in or out of stock), so if the parent product is in stock it shows up

Comment: @bayanelshiwy , can you please check the above code as i have modified for variation. it will hide variation option for out of stock. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

I am using WOOF product filter plugin, so i found that i need to put this code in functions.php to only get in stock products filter

```
add_filter('woof_get_request_data', 'my_woof_get_request_data');

function my_woof_get_request_data($data){
    $data['stock']='instock';
    return $data;
}
```